NEXTJs API : Using formdata to upload file is breaking in the hosted site, while works on local environment
The below code is my client-api.ts uploadPOMedia function
export const uploadPOMedia = async (props: any) => {
  

  const res =  await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/upload-po-document",
    data: props,
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("Response Status : " + res.status + " Response :" +res.data);

  return res.data;
};


Also I tried its alternative fetch function utilizing the following code but no-luck in this one too.
export const uploadPOMedia = async (props: any) => {
  const res: any = await fetch("/api/upload-po-document", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      cache: "no-store",
    },
    body: props,
  });
  const response = await res.json();
  return response;
};


The route.ts for this upload-po-document route contains below code.
import { uploadPODocument } from "@agents/CheckoutAgent";
import { ErrorStack } from "@utils/Helpers/HelperUtility";
import { AREA } from "@utils/Logging/Areas";
import logger from "@utils/Logging/Logger";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const dataResponse = await request.formData();
    const fileEntry = dataResponse.get("file");
    if (fileEntry instanceof Blob) {
      const file = new File([fileEntry], fileEntry.name);
      const fileData = await uploadPODocument(file);
      return Response.json(fileData);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(AREA.Checkout, ErrorStack(error));
    return new Response("Internal server error.", {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}


and I call the uploadPOMedia function from my .tsx file (view level file) , the call for the mediaupload contains the following code.
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
          await uploadPOMedia(formData).then((x) => (poDocumentPath = x));


So basically, we are creating formdata from file and then calling uploadPOMedia.
Now, the problem here I am facing is whenever I test my code locally, or even by creating production build locally, it works. I can debug the server side code (i.e, route.ts) and I get dataResponse object and fileEntry object too as the file.
But on the hosted site, this breaks.I am getting the following errors in my console from client-api.ts
Console Errors on hosted site.

You have a server side error, what does the log for catch (error) {
logger.error(AREA.Checkout, ErrorStack(error)); show you?

Even the request is not reaching to that code block

So the problem was with the if statement.
  if (fileEntry instanceof Blob) 

In the Local environment it was returning true, and in the hosted site was returning false
